# Promoting a specific Build in Artifactory to a different repository

Tags: artifactory

Can I get some help on promoting a build using REST API with cURL command.
I have been successful in updating the status using the below syntax:

```
curl -X POST -u admin:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"status":"tests passed","ciUser":"jenkinsAdmin"}' "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/build/promote/buildName/buildNumber"
```

But, unable to move the build from one repository to another. My aim to, promote the build from one repository to another when I run the cURL command with parameters. So that my build is moved to other repository and the status gets updated too.

I also get the below message when I run the curl command:

```
{"level":"INFO","message":"Skipping build item relocation: no target repository selected."}
```

This post relates to the question about [changing existing build status in artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097401/how-to-change-an-existing-build-status-in-artifactory-from-a-jenkins-job)

Please Advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [in the documentation](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BuildPromotion), you just need to set the `targetRepo` parameter. Please note the snapshot-release handling policy in the target repository.

Comment: worked, Thanks!!! I couldn't find the exact parameter for the target repository. That was just simple. One more query, I am looking for promotion with leaving a copy back in the existing repo. Is there a way. I couldn't find this either.

Comment: Is there a way, I can just promote that specific build number? Because, when I promote a build, it actually moves all old builds from the current repository to the new repo. Not just the specified build number.

Comment: What do you mean? In the URL of promotion you specify the build number as a last path token:
`http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/build/promote/buildName/buildNumber`

Comment: I have configured 3 repositories (Dev, Test and Prod), my build gets copied to DEV first (there are more old builds in DEV at this point) and when I run the URL for promotion to Test repo, my DEV repo goes blank and my old builds are also referring to Test repo, not just the new build. Does it make sense ?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Please write to support@jfrog.com, they'll try to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

See if this script can help. 
https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/8a06563d853995ea7f59f0f5f3a67bcb08b5c2e9/build/promotion/promotion.groovy

**PS**: Every team / company have different requirements, rules/policies on what to promote (artifacts), how to promote (steps) and what checks/rules/conditions/policies that I should make sure are true/false or set/passed before doing any promotion step; so change this code according to your needs.

Also check these: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-PromotingBuildsinArtifactory on how you can do the same within Jenkins **and** for fun, look here: [Delete jenkins builds during Promote / promotion step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861950/delete-jenkins-builds-during-promote-promotion-step) if you want to do some maintenance in Jenkins or in Artifactory.

Comment: why is build promotion an Artifactory plugin? isn't it possible to specify promotion processes only on the Jenkins side?