# Do not delete a Jenkins build if it's marked as "Keep this build forever" - Groovy script to delete Jenkins builds

Tags: groovy, jenkins, build, forever

I have the following Groovy script which deletes all builds of a given Jenkins job except one build number that user provides (i.e. wants to retain).

```
/*** BEGIN META {
  "name" : "Bulk Delete Builds except the given build number",
  "comment" : "For a given job and a given build number, delete all build except the user provided one.",
  "parameters" : [ 'jobName', 'buildNumber' ],
  "core": "1.409",
  "authors" : [
     { name : "Arun Sangal" }
  ]
} END META **/


// NOTE: Uncomment parameters below if not using Scriptler >= 2.0, or if you're just pasting the script in manually.
// ----- Logic in this script takes 5000 as the infinite number, decrease / increase this value from your own experience.
// The name of the job.
//def jobName = "some-job"

// The range of build numbers to delete.
//def buildNumber = "5"

def lastBuildNumber = buildNumber.toInteger() - 1;
def nextBuildNumber = buildNumber.toInteger() + 1;


import jenkins.model.*;
import hudson.model.Fingerprint.RangeSet;

def jij = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName);

println("Keeping Job_Name: ${jobName} and build Number: ${buildNumber}");
println ""

def setBuildRange = "1-${lastBuildNumber}"
def range = RangeSet.fromString(setBuildRange, true);
jij.getBuilds(range).each { it.delete() }
println("Builds have been deleted - Range: " + setBuildRange)

setBuildRange = "${nextBuildNumber}-5000"
range = RangeSet.fromString(setBuildRange, true);
jij.getBuilds(range).each { it.delete() }
println("Builds have been deleted - Range: " + setBuildRange)
```

This works well for any Jenkins job. For ex: If your Jenkins job name is "TestJob" and you have 15 builds i.e. build# 1 to build 15 in Jenkins, and you want to delete all but retain build# 13, then this script will delete the builds (build# 1-12 and 14-15 - even if you mark any build as "Keep this build forever") and only keep build#13.

**Now, what I want is:**

1. what should I change in this script to not delete a build - if a build is marked in Jenkins as "Keep this build forever". I tried the script and it deleted that keep forever build too.
2. Lets say, if I'm using "Build name setter plugin" in Jenkins, which can give me build names as what name I want i.e. instead of getting just build as build#1 or #2, or #15, I will get build as build# 2.75.0.1, 2.75.0.2, 2.75.0.3, ..... , 2.75.0.15 (as I would have set the build name/description as use some variable which contains 2.75.0 (as a release version value) and suffixed it with the actual Jenkins job's build number i.e. the last 4th digit - ex: set the name as:

   ```
   ${ENV,var="somepropertyvariable"}.${BUILD_NUMBER}
   ```

   In this case, I'll start getting Jenkins builds as 2.75.0.1 to 2.75.0.x (where x is the last build# of that release (2.75.0)). Similarly, when I'll change the property release version to next i.e. 2.75.1 or 2.76.0, then the same Jenkins job will start giving me builds as 2.75.1.0, 2.75.1.1, ...., 2.75.1.x or 2.76.0.1, 2.76.0.2, ...., 2.76.0.x and so on. During the release version change, let say, our build will start from 1 again (as I mentioned above for 2.75.1 and 2.76.0 release versions).

   In this case, if my Jenkins job's build history (shows all builds for 2.75.0.x, 2.75.1.x and 2.76.0.x), then what change should I make in this script to include a 3rd parameter/argument. This 3rd argument will take release /version value i.e. either 2.75.0 or 2.75.1 or 2.76.0 and then this script should delete build numbers on that release only (and should NOT delete other release's builds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - Solution for my question 2 is here: I'm still working on fixing question 1.

http://scriptlerweb.appspot.com/script/show/102001

**bulkDeleteJenkinsBuildsExceptOne_OfAGivenRelease.groovy**

```
/*** BEGIN META {
  "name" : "Bulk Delete Builds except the given build number",
  "comment" : "For a given job and a given build numnber, delete all builds of a given release version (M.m.interim) only and except the user provided one. Sometimes a Jenkins job use Build Name setter plugin and same job generates 2.75.0.1 and 2.76.0.43",
  "parameters" : [ 'jobName', 'releaseVersion', 'buildNumber' ],
  "core": "1.409",
  "authors" : [
     { name : "Arun Sangal" }
  ]
} END META **/


// NOTE: Uncomment parameters below if not using Scriptler >= 2.0, or if you're just pasting the script in manually.
// ----- Logic in this script takes 5000 as the infinite number, decrease / increase this value from your own experience.
// The name of the job.
//def jobName = "some-job"

// The release / version of a Jenkins job - i.e. in case you use "Build name" setter plugin in Jenkins for getting builds like 2.75.0.1, 2.75.0.2, .. , 2.75.0.15 etc.
// and over the time, change the release/version value (2.75.0) to a newer value i.e. 2.75.1 or 2.76.0 and start builds of this new release/version from #1 onwards.
//def releaseVersion = "2.75.0"

// The range of build numbers to delete.
//def buildNumber = "5"

def lastBuildNumber = buildNumber.toInteger() - 1;
def nextBuildNumber = buildNumber.toInteger() + 1;


import jenkins.model.*;
import hudson.model.Fingerprint.RangeSet;

def jij = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName);
//def build = jij.getLastBuild();

println ""
println("- Jenkins Job_Name: ${jobName} -- Version: ${releaseVersion} -- Keep Build Number: ${buildNumber}");
println ""
println "  -- Range before given build number: ${buildNumber}"
println ""

def setBuildRange = "1-${lastBuildNumber}"
def range = RangeSet.fromString(setBuildRange, true);
jij.getBuilds(range).each {
  if ( it.getDisplayName().find(/${releaseVersion}.*/)) {
     println "     ## Deleting >>>>>>>>>: " + it.getDisplayName();

     // Trying to find - how to NOT delete a build in Jenkins if it's marked as "keep this build forever". If someone has an idea, please update this script with a newer version in GitHub.
     //if ( !build.isKeepLog()) {
          it.delete();
     //} else {
     //   println "build -- can't be deleted as :" + build.getWhyKeepLog();
     //}
  }
}



println ""
println "  -- Range after  given build number: ${buildNumber}"
println ""
setBuildRange = "${nextBuildNumber}-5000"
range = RangeSet.fromString(setBuildRange, true);
jij.getBuilds(range).each {
  if ( it.getDisplayName().find(/${releaseVersion}.*/)) {
     println "     ## Deleting >>>>>>>>>: " + it.getDisplayName();
     it.delete();
  }
}

println ""
println("- Builds have been successfully deleted for the above mentioned release: ${releaseVersion}")
println ""
```

[image]

One can also call this script via a Jenkins job (requires 3 parameters as mentioned in the scriptler script) -OR call it from browser as well: using the following link:

http ://YourJenkinsServerName:PORT/job/Some_Jenkins_Job_That_You_Will_Create/buildWithParameters?jobName=Test_AppSvc&releaseVersion=2.75.0&buildNumber=15

Comment: This script will run fine using Jenkins "Scriptler" plugin. See attached image for output. If you want to run this script from a Jenkins job, then under Build section, call Scriptler script, provide the location/file name, check box that the jenkins job will consume the parameters for this scriptler script (shown above), that's it. This jenkins job needs 3 parameter String format - jobName, releaseVersion and buildNumber.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test whether a build has been marked permanent, use

```
if (!build.isKeepLog()) {
    // Build can be deleted
} else {
    // Build is marked permanent
}
```

I think you should be able to use the [getName() method](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Item.html#getName%28%29) on each build to check whether you should delete a given build.  The API JavaDoc can be fairly obscure, so I often go on [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci) and look through the code for a Jenkins plugin that's doing something similar to what I need.  The [public Scriptler repository](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/tree/master/scriptler) can be useful, too.

Comment: From where am I getting this "build" (in build.isKeepLog), thanks

Comment: build = jij.getLastBuild(); if ( !build.isKeepLog()) returns false in both case - either if the build is marked to be kept forever -or not.

Comment: That doesn't sound right; I have scripts that use isKeepLog() to control whether a build is permanent and they are working fine.  Could you post your entire script somewhere and I'll take a look ?

Comment: Sure. I did try including it, set the build keep forever, it returns false when i println the build.isKeepLog(). Please See my FINAL answer script which does deletion from both Jenkins and Artifactory builds artifacts of a given release/version of a Jenkins job. If you can make that script - not delete the "Keep forever" builds, that would be awesome.

Comment: You have to include your logic of if (!build.isKeepLog()) ... just before the line: it.delete(); in the final script.

Answer (score 1):

**Final Answer:** This includes deleting the build artifacts from Artifactory as well using Artifactor's REST API call. This script will delete Jenkins/Artifactory builds/artifacts of a given Release/Version (as sometimes over the time - a given Jenkins job can create multiple release / version builds for ex: 2.75.0.1, 2.75.0.2, 2.75.0.3,....,2.75.0.54, 2.76.0.1, 2.76.0.2, ..., 2.76.0.16, 2.76.1.1, 2.76.1.2, ...., 2.76.1.5). In this case, for every new release of that job, we start the build# from 1 fresh. If you have to delete the all builds except one / even all (change the script a little bit for your own needs) and don't change older/other release builds, then use the following script.

**Scriptler Catalog link**: http://scriptlerweb.appspot.com/script/show/103001

**Enjoy!**

```
/*** BEGIN META {
  "name" : "Bulk Delete Builds except the given build number",
  "comment" : "For a given job and a given build numnber, delete all builds of a given release version (M.m.interim) only and except the user provided one. Sometimes a Jenkins job use Build Name setter plugin and same job generates 2.75.0.1 and 2.76.0.43",
  "parameters" : [ 'jobName', 'releaseVersion', 'buildNumber' ],
  "core": "1.409",
  "authors" : [
     { name : "Arun Sangal - Maddys Version" }
  ]
} END META **/

import groovy.json.*
import jenkins.model.*;
import hudson.model.Fingerprint.RangeSet;
import hudson.model.Job;
import hudson.model.Fingerprint;

//these should be passed in as arguments to the script
if(!artifactoryURL) throw new Exception("artifactoryURL not provided")
if(!artifactoryUser) throw new Exception("artifactoryUser not provided")
if(!artifactoryPassword) throw new Exception("artifactoryPassword not provided")
def authString = "${artifactoryUser}:${artifactoryPassword}".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
def artifactorySettings = [artifactoryURL: artifactoryURL, authString: authString]

if(!jobName) throw new Exception("jobName not provided")
if(!buildNumber) throw new Exception("buildNumber not provided")

def lastBuildNumber = buildNumber.toInteger() - 1;
def nextBuildNumber = buildNumber.toInteger() + 1;

def jij = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName);

def promotedBuildRange = new Fingerprint.RangeSet()
promotedBuildRange.add(buildNumber.toInteger())
def promoteBuildsList = jij.getBuilds(promotedBuildRange)
assert promoteBuildsList.size() == 1
def promotedBuild = promoteBuildsList[0]
// The release / version of a Jenkins job - i.e. in case you use "Build name" setter plugin in Jenkins for getting builds like 2.75.0.1, 2.75.0.2, .. , 2.75.0.15 etc.
// and over the time, change the release/version value (2.75.0) to a newer value i.e. 2.75.1 or 2.76.0 and start builds of this new release/version from #1 onwards.
def releaseVersion = promotedBuild.getDisplayName().split("\\.")[0..2].join(".")

println ""
println("- Jenkins Job_Name: ${jobName} -- Version: ${releaseVersion} -- Keep Build Number: ${buildNumber}");
println ""

/** delete the indicated build and its artifacts from artifactory */
def deleteBuildFromArtifactory(String jobName, int deleteBuildNumber, Map<String, String> artifactorySettings){
    println "     ## Deleting >>>>>>>>>: - ${jobName}:${deleteBuildNumber} from artifactory"
                                def artifactSearchUri = "api/build/${jobName}?buildNumbers=${deleteBuildNumber}&artifacts=1"
                                def conn = "${artifactorySettings['artifactoryURL']}/${artifactSearchUri}".toURL().openConnection()
                                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + artifactorySettings['authString']);
                                conn.setRequestMethod("DELETE")
    if( conn.responseCode != 200 ) {
        println "Failed to delete the build artifacts from artifactory for ${jobName}/${deleteBuildNumber}: ${conn.responseCode} - ${conn.responseMessage}"
    }
}

/** delete all builds in the indicated range that match the releaseVersion */
def deleteBuildsInRange(String buildRange, String releaseVersion, Job theJob, Map<String, String> artifactorySettings){
    def range = RangeSet.fromString(buildRange, true);
    theJob.getBuilds(range).each {
        if ( it.getDisplayName().find(/${releaseVersion}.*/)) {
            println "     ## Deleting >>>>>>>>>: " + it.getDisplayName();
            deleteBuildFromArtifactory(theJob.name, it.number, artifactorySettings)
            it.delete();
        }
    }
}

//delete all the matching builds before the promoted build number
deleteBuildsInRange("1-${lastBuildNumber}", releaseVersion, jij, artifactorySettings)

//delete all the matching builds after the promoted build number
deleteBuildsInRange("${nextBuildNumber}-${jij.nextBuildNumber}", releaseVersion, jij, artifactorySettings)

println ""
println("- Builds have been successfully deleted for the above mentioned release: ${releaseVersion}")
println ""
```