# Delete and/or Replace Artifacts in Nexus using Gradle

Tags: gradle, nexus

I am still new to Gradle and Nexus.

I want to be able to remove artifact from a hosted nexus repository with Gradle. Using the nexus GUI in order to do this is not an option, because I don't wanna.

Part of the reason for wanting this is to be able to automatically correct upload errors such as incorrectly labeled artifacts, or artifacts uploaded with he wrong version. I may also just want to wipe out an entire project and all versions of it (maybe because it was uploaded to the wrong repo, or I'm just doing some house cleaning. OR perhaps I want to overwrite the currently up-loaded version of an artifact. Anyways, I don't have a real use case right now, but I still want to know how to do it.

Edit: Also, I'm curious about ways to "gracefully" handle times when a certain artifact version is already uploaded, such as catching a specific exception and outputting a user friendly message to advise the developer to update the build version before uploading.

Here's my current uploadArtifact task.

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'repos'
        }
        mavenDeployer {
            credentials {
                username "user"
                password "password"
            }
            url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use Groovy (first class citizen in Gradle) to perform any operation in Nexus. Similar to Nexus, we have Artifactory and I used REST API approach to delete artifacts from Artifactory repository. You can tweak the code a little bit to do the same for Nexus. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861950/delete-jenkins-builds-during-promote-promotion-step and my script also uses REST API to delete some old builds from Jenkins (REST API way) but you can ignore that part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything built into Gradle to manage a Nexus repository. Unless you find a third-party Gradle plugin for this, you'll have to develop your own solution. For example, you could  write one or more Gradle tasks that use Nexus' REST APIs to accomplish what you want.

PS: Maven repositories are designed to be immutable, and changing any data or metadata after it has been published is generally frowned upon. (Instead a new version should be published that fixes the problem.) For such a change to take affect, *every* developer and CI machine will have to run all affected builds with `--refresh-dependencies` in order to invalidate the local cache (or wipe out the whole cache). This will likely cause *lots* of pain.

Comment: I agree. REST API way. I gave him a little example (where I did the same using Artifactory).

Comment: You've got me convinced about never deleting commits. Do you have any advice on how to gracefully handle errors when trying to upload a version that already exists? I thought the default exception message was not very clean.